# commands vs subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Just wondering if anybody could tell me why

```
import subprocess, commands

p=subprocess.Popen(["ls", "*00080"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output=p.communicate()[0]
print "o", output
result=commands.getoutput("ls *00080")
print "o", result
```

gives the outputs:

```
o ls: cannot access *00080: No such file or directory

o 010.010.013.165.42974-010.010.013.164.00080
```

Both should find the file shouldn't they?

A

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`commands` spaws a shell which does the glob expansion.  `subprocess` doesn't spawn a shell unless you pass `shell = True`.

In other words:

```
p=subprocess.Popen("ls *00080",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

should do the same thing that `commands` did.